# Spring integration flow: perform task within flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

hopefully this one is the last question I'm asking on spring integration.

Faced following problem: at the end of pretty long IntegrationFlow dsl sheet there is a code:

```
   return IntegrationFlows.
   //...
       .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header("jms_replyTo", responseQueue(), true)) // IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID is not acceptable though message came from outgoingGateway of another application with this header been set
       .handle(requestRepository::save)
       .handle(
            Jms.outboundAdapter(queueConnectionFactory()).destination(serverQueue())
       )
       .get();
```

The problem is that after some code like `requestRepository::save` handlers chain becomes broken. This trick only works if there is a gateway passed in as a handler parameter.

How can I overcome this limitation? I think that utilizing wireTap here will not make a deal because it is asynchromous. Here, actually, I save message to store it's `jms_replyTo` header and replace it with saved one after corresponding reply comes back from server (Smart Proxy enterprise integration pattern).

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why do you say "the last question". Are you going to give up on Spring Integration? :-(

I guess your problem there with the next `.handle()` because your `requestRepository::save` is one-way `MessageHandler` (the `void` return from the `save()` method). Or your `save()` returns `null`.

The `IntegrationFlow` is a chain of executions when the next one will be called after the previous with its non-null result.

So, share your `requestRepository::save`, please!

**UPDATE**

> Neither did help declaring MessageHandler bean as a (m) -> requestRepository.save(m) and passing it into handle(..) method as a param.

Yeah... I would like to see the signature for your `requestRepository::save`.

So, look. Using method reference for the `.handle()` you should determine your scenario. If you do `one-way` handle with the flow stop, there is enough to follow with the `org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler` contract. with that you method signature should be like this:

```
public void myHandle(Message<?> message)
```

If you'd like to go ahead with the flow you should return anything from your service method. And that result becomes the `payload` for the next `.handle()`.
In this case your method should follow with the `org.springframework.integration.dsl.support.GenericHandler` contract. Your method signature may look like:

```
public Bar myHandle(Foo foo, Map<String, Object> headers)
```

That's how the method reference works for the `.handle()`.

You should understand how this `method chain` style works. The output of the previous method is an input of the next. In this our case we protect the flow from the dead code, like `MessageHandler` with `void` return, but there is the next flow member. That's why you see `This is the end of the integration flow.` error.

Comment: Right, request repo's `save` method returns nothing. I have no code right now before my eyes, but it just saves message into db  and method declared as `void`. (No, I'm saying the last because I have a feeling I'm asking to often.) Thanks for advice, will try to return value.

Comment: :-). No problem for asking! I don't feel good in many other things, so I'm forced to ask too. From other side it is my work to answer to similar questions and help people to understand and use Framework. From other side such a feedback like yours help us make the Framework better. As for now it looks like the documentation or JavaDocs aren't clear and this invocation chain should be explained better.

Comment: Exactly, Artem. That's what I just wanted to notice. Spring framework is a masterpiece and it's documentation has always been pretty and helpful. But spring integration seems to be a bit more complicated module than others. Documentation shows every aspect separately, but it's hard to understand how to combine all the pieces together. My colleagues opinions are the same. Would be very glad if you improve documentation just a little bit to describe how to organize flows. 
(One more question - are there any integration patterns you are going to implement in future in this module?) Thank you.

Comment: Returning String or boolean from `save` method didn't make sense. I keep using code above and framework says: `The 'currentComponent' (c.e.m.integration.orchestrator.conf.IntegrationConfig$$Lambda$3/632206764@127a7272) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.`

Comment: Neither did help declaring `MessageHandler` bean as a `(m) -> requestRepository.save(m)` and passing it into `handle(..)` method as a param.

Answer (score 0):

Finally came up with solution:

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler requestPersistingHandler() {
    return new ServiceActivatingHandler(message -> {
        requestRepository.save(message);
        return message.getPayload();
    });
}

//...
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(queueConnectionFactory()).destination(bookingQueue())
    )
            .wireTap(controlBusMessageChannel())
            .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header(JMS_REPLY_HEADER, responseQueue(), true))
            .handle(requestPersistingHandler())
            .handle(
                    Jms.outboundAdapter(queueConnectionFactory()).destination(serverQueue())
            )
            .get();
}
```

I'm just not sure if there is some more straight way.

The only issue left is how to change header in "from-the-server" IntegrationFlow within `enrichHeaders` method: have no idea how to access existing headers with specification.